# Process ID instead of port Address

Tags: networking

I have been to one confusion that when i request certain web page from my computer let us say www.example.com then my computer will make request to DNS server to find the IP Address of the destination and it will bind the source ip,destination ip and source port for finding which application was there to request the web page. And my question is that if i request from chrome (let us say) then it has already a certain process id associated with it. why don't we use that process id instead of port address? I know that socket id should be associated as it identifies the different application running inside the chrome in this example.
Sorry if my concept is wrong.

Comment: The port needs to be unique for each connection. One process can have multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: not sure why so many downvotes as I looked this up to answer the same question asked in my COMP 3271 (networks) course at a Canadian university.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A port is a logical id for a service. You can see these port ids on a Unix system by opening up /etc/services. Here's an example couple of lines that define the ports for SMTP:

`smtp             25/udp     # Simple Mail Transfer
smtp             25/tcp     # Simple Mail Transfer`

These services are well known. They don't vary. Conversely, the process ID of a daemon that handles a service (like SMTP) will vary, most likely across reboots and quite possibly it will vary within a single instance of a server boot (e.g., an admin stops and restarts it will cause it to get a new process ID).

The service ID/port has to be unique so that applications can specify where on a server the packets being received should be sent. It's just a short way of saying "send my packets to this application/service". The ID could just have been a string or name such as "webserver", "emailserver", "ftpserver" but that would not be as efficient as a short integer ID to send, but it is effectively the same concept - whether a string or an id, it identifies a service.

Well, you might ask, what if you had a service (kind of like DNS) that you called to say "give me the process ID of the smtp server"? First off, why do that when you can just say "send this to the smtp server" to begin with? You do that by embedding the port number in each packet sent (it's a field in each TCP/UDP packet sent by the client). Secondly, that process ID would have to be valid for the duration of the client session, but as I mentioned, processes can be stopped and restarted, meaning the process ID for the service could change. Hence, static, agreed upon port numbers are used; process ids are at best inefficient (because of the lookup you'd need to do to find them out), and worse simply not reliable (because process IDs change).

IP addresses tell you what machine/host to route the packets (destined for SMTP are to be sent). IP address of a machine can change, and that is one reason why you need something like DNS to translate a name (e.g., www.google.com) into an IP address. In contrast, the number of services [text file with IANA port number assignments](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt) is small enough to represent locally (in /etc/services for example) on each host, no need for some kind of lookup service (not to mention that port numbers are usually only something that the programmer of the service, or of the client, needs to be aware of).

By analogy, everyone's home is at a different street address/city. This is what IP addresses provide, a way to find a server/host on the Internet. DNS is like asking a service to answer the question "what is the address of Joe Smith?".

Now that we can find the home, we need to agree on terminology for rooms in the home. By convention, everyone calls their bedroom "bedroom". This is analogous to identifying a service within the server as a port number.

So much for the port of a well known service on the server side, and how clients can address it. If you are asking about how ports are assigned for client connections, or for connections that are made by children or threads of the server that are bound to a specific client (typically, a server will spawn a thread of child process and carry out the transaction over a different connection than the one listening for clients on), then ephemeral ports (in a specific assigned range) are often used. In this case, the client and server don't particularly care the port number because they've already found each other, so to speak, and these port numbers will vary and are effectively random (at least to the client and server using them). These port numbers cannot truly be random, however, because they may conflict with the port assignments used by well known services or the range of ports available for use explicitly by services that are not registered with the IANA. They come from a reserved range that the IANA has set aside for this purpose. Just using the PID of the process does not ensure the port will not conflict with another port, or be in the range assigned for this purpose.

Comment: You are talking about the destination (server) port but the OP is asking about the source port on the client initiating the connection.

Comment: Yep, could be. The question was hard to decipher - I added a paragraph talking a bit about ephmeral ports and why they much not conflict with the range of assigned ports - this makes PIDs useless because they could overlap.